# Pipelining redisearch-py commands

Tags: python, redis, redisearch

Is there a way to send multiple redisearch commands in a single pipeline using redisearch-py client? Also is it possible to mix the classic redis commands with the redisearch commands in the same pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, for both your questions.
IIRC some commands will not work in transactions or Lua scripts but pipelines weren't a problem.